# Проблема при отправке на проверку

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Ребят, кто может объяснить, что за используемые права и как устранить?  Интегрировал приложение с `healthkit`, из приложения передаю только время тренировки и калории, в приложение никаких данных из `healthkit` не принимаю. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе в `info.plist` (или в настройках таргета на вкладке `Info`) нужно добавить ключ (это будет массив) `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` с элементом-строкой `healthkit`. Это разрешит ставить программу только на девайсы, поддерживающие `healthkit`.

PS: правильный ответ - в апдейте существующего приложения нельзя ограничивать семейства или какие-то модели девайсов, которые поддерживались раньше. Нужно или регистрировать новое приложение или проверять наличие классов и методов из кода.

Comment: А где этот ключ брать? можно пример?

Comment: ключ это строка (как для NSDictionary), можешь скопировать ее из моего ответа. Значения можешь взять тут - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3
А получиться должно так - http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/armv7.png

Comment: А у меня уже автоматом оказывается все было... Скрин добавил в вопрос. Что тогда?

Comment: так, а это ты апдейт прошлого приложения делаешь? Тогда придется регистрировать новое приложение - в новых версиях нельзя ограничивать семейства или какие-то модели девайсов.

Comment: Т.е. вообще новое приложение выпускать, а старое забрасывать? или я не правильно понял?

Comment: К сожалению - правильно. Хотя старое можно не забрасывать, можно его параллельно вести. Ну, если там много клиентов

Comment: А удалить ограничения, не пропустят или не будет работать?

Comment: Попробуй. Но я не уверен что так healthkit будет работать. Но если будет, то нужно будет сделать проверку на его наличие из кода.

Comment: Я новичек, не знаю как.. подскажи как проверку делать, спасибо

Comment: На лету проверку можно сделать так (если нужен класс):
if ([TheWantedClass class]) {
    // The class exists so run code
} else {
    // The class doesn't exist so use an alternate approach
}

или так

if (NSClassFromString(@"TheWantedClass") != nil) {
    // The class exists
} else {
    // The class doesn't exist
}

Если класс есть и нужно проверить наличие метода - 
if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(methodName:withEtc:)]) {
   [obj methodName:123 withEtc:456];
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732863/objective-c-check-if-a-method-exist

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182668/objective-c-detect-if-class-is-available-for-different-os-versions